# How to get toast element that fades away quickly with protractor

Tags: reactjs, protractor

I have a toast element in UI(which shows up to show success message and fades away in few seconds). How do I get message from that element for my automation script? I tried below code but I am getting undefined:

````
        toastMessage = $('.fluid-toaster--success');
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(toastMessage),20000, 'timeout');
        return this.findElement(this.by.xpath("//p[@class='fluid-toaster__msg']") );
    } }```
````

Comment: Base on your code you try to it like a js dom not like a reactjs lifecycle...I suggest to re-think how you can share text nested of get it via dom...

for example you can use state if its in same component, context if its shareable between more than one component or props if you like flow down...

or at least, you can create ref and use it to get text nested of use js...what do you think?

Comment: I am looking to get this component in my automation script which is written using Selenium protractor

Comment: mm, Thank you for explain, I'm not an expert in this field, I will vote up...

Comment: selenium? you have protractor tag, not selenium

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov : Script is written using Protractor. btw, I was able to fix this issue. Thanks for your comment